# How do you repeat a WMA in Media Player with no gaps?

Tags: audio, windows-media-player, playback, wma

I've set up Windows Media Player with a playlist that plays the same WMA twice. I've also set it to repeat (loop).

This is somewhat Ok for no gaps during transition, but once every 10 minutes, I'll pick up a gap. Is there a better way to set this up?

My WMA is about 30 seconds long, and I want it to play indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For troubleshooting and identifying purposes you could try a different media player. This might also fix the issue.

How long does it loop for? If finite and/or fixed, you could use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) or another audio editor to copy and paste the clips together.

Edit: Audacity doesn't support .wma files to you'd have to convert or use another editor, sorry!

Comment: I want it to loop indefinitely. In the end, if I don't get a better solution, I will try other media players. I just wanted to minimize the number of apps on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

The *JRiver* **Media Jukebox** can be set to play whatever length of audio file repeatedly ad infinitum---and crossfade the track(s) as it does so.
Just import the track(s) to the player, add them to '***Playing now***', set the fade in/out appropriately (via Tools> Options> Player) and hit *Play*.

Comment: I actually used Media Jukebox quite a bit 10 or so years ago. I really did like it. I may just have to check it out again.